# Python - dump dict as a json string

Tags: python, json

What am I missing?  I want to dump a dictionary as a json string.

I am using python 2.7

With this code:

```
import json
fu = {'a':'b'}
output = json.dump(fu)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent-1.0b2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/gevent/greenlet.py", line 328, in run
    result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/bitmagister-api/mab.py", line 117, in mabLoop
    output = json.dump(fu)
TypeError: dump() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
<Greenlet at 0x7f4f3d6eec30: mabLoop> failed with TypeError
```

Comment: @kampu Some research failure but not *severe*, leaving out one letter of a function call is no big deal, maybe just an accident. An attempt and error  are showing so according to SO guidelines so it follows the site format.

Comment: My "research" led me here, so this is not a pointless question. Better he ask here and in so doing answer 10,825 viewers' question than leave them wondering where to start to look for the problem.
This is why StackOverflow is a thing.  RTFM is actually difficult, and often insufficient.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Dictionary to JSON in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745519/converting-dictionary-to-json-in-python)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use `json.dumps` to dump a `str`

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({'a':'b'})
'{"a": "b"}'
```

`json.dump` dumps to a file

Answer (score 12):

i think the problem is json.dump. try

```
json.dumps(fu)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `json.dumps`.

Example:

```
import json

json.dumps({'zuckerberg':'tech','sachin':'cricket'})
```

This outputs:

```
'{"zuckerberg": "tech", "sachin": "cricket"}'
```

If you want to sort the keys, use `sort_keys` as the second argument to `json.dumps`:

```
json.dumps({'zuckerberg':'tech','sachin':'cricket'},sort_keys=True)
```

Outputs:

```
'{"sachin": "cricket", "zuckerberg": "tech"}'
```

Comment: thanks Drenmi for formating , was new to stackoverflow ,i will improve next time while answering

Comment: `sort_keys` is nice for debugging

Answer (score 0):

```py
message={"message":"Done", "result":"1"}
message_json = simplejson.dumps(message)
payload = message_json

##or 
message={"message":"Done", "result":"1"}
message_json=jsonify(message)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//s.tk/meta/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post.