# Converting dictionary to JSON

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

```
r = {'is_claimed': 'True', 'rating': 3.5}
r = json.dumps(r)
file.write(str(r['rating']))
```

I am not able to access my data in the JSON. What am I doing wrong?

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: See [json.dumps()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66070438/13155046)

Answer (score 807, accepted):

`json.dumps()` converts a dictionary to `str` object, not a `json(dict)` object! So you have to load your `str` into a `dict` to use it by using [**`json.loads()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) method

See `json.dumps()` as a save method and `json.loads()` as a retrieve method.

This is the code sample which might help you understand it more:

```
import json

r = {'is_claimed': 'True', 'rating': 3.5}
r = json.dumps(r)
loaded_r = json.loads(r)
loaded_r['rating'] #Output 3.5
type(r) #Output str
type(loaded_r) #Output dict
```

Comment: don't you think it's a bit inefficient to load the json back into a separate variable `loaded_r`, considering you already had it in `r`?

Comment: Hi! I realize this is a very old answer, but I was hoping you could clear one thing up. @TimCastelijns mentioned that it's inefficient to load the json back into a new variable loaded_r.   

Would the efficient way of doing this be to just state r = json.loads(r)?

Comment: @SchrodingersStat Hi. I don't think this changes performance a lot. You can check using the 'timeit' function. If you really want a fast json load/dump, you can use the 'ujson' library!

Comment: I suspect @TimCastelijns has misunderstood Imran's intent. The JSON is loaded into a new variable not because it is new information, but to show that the values in the new dictionary, i.e. after the JSON encode and decode round-trip, are identical.

Comment: you can dump as json file too, like this

`with open('r.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(r, json_file)
`

Answer (score 73):

`json.dumps()` returns the JSON string representation of the python dict. [See the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps)

You can't do `r['rating']` because r is a string, not a dict anymore

Perhaps you meant something like

```
r = {'is_claimed': 'True', 'rating': 3.5}
json = json.dumps(r) # note i gave it a different name
file.write(str(r['rating']))
```

Answer (score 55):

#### [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) is used to decode JSON data

- `json.loads` take a string as input and returns a dictionary as output.
- `json.dumps` take a dictionary as input and returns a string as output.

```py
import json

# initialize different data
str_data = 'normal string'
int_data = 1
float_data = 1.50
list_data = [str_data, int_data, float_data]
nested_list = [int_data, float_data, list_data]
dictionary = {
    'int': int_data,
    'str': str_data,
    'float': float_data,
    'list': list_data,
    'nested list': nested_list
}

# convert them to JSON data and then print it
print('String :', json.dumps(str_data))
print('Integer :', json.dumps(int_data))
print('Float :', json.dumps(float_data))
print('List :', json.dumps(list_data))
print('Nested List :', json.dumps(nested_list, indent=4))
print('Dictionary :', json.dumps(dictionary, indent=4))  # the json data will be indented
```

output:

```sh
String : "normal string"
Integer : 1
Float : 1.5
List : ["normal string", 1, 1.5]
Nested List : [
    1,
    1.5,
    [
        "normal string",
        1,
        1.5
    ]
]
Dictionary : {
    "int": 1,
    "str": "normal string",
    "float": 1.5,
    "list": [
        "normal string",
        1,
        1.5
    ],
    "nested list": [
        1,
        1.5,
        [
            "normal string",
            1,
            1.5
        ]
    ]
}
```

- Python Object to JSON Data Conversion

```sh
|                 Python                 |  JSON  |
|:--------------------------------------:|:------:|
|                  dict                  | object |
|               list, tuple              |  array |
|                   str                  | string |
| int, float, int- & float-derived Enums | number |
|                  True                  |  true  |
|                  False                 |  false |
|                  None                  |  null  |
```

### UPDATE

#### In the JSON file

```py
nested_dictionary = {
    'one': nested_list,
    'two': dictionary,

}

json_dict = {'Nested Dictionary': nested_dictionary,
             'Multiple':[nested_dictionary, nested_dictionary, nested_dictionary]
            }

with open("test_nested.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(json_dict, outfile, indent=4, sort_keys=False)
```

chart response

[image]

output into `test_nested.json`

```sh
{
    "Nested Dictionary": {
        "one": [
            1,
            1.5,
            [
                "normal string",
                1,
                1.5
            ]
        ],
        "two": {
            "int": 1,
            "str": "normal string",
            "float": 1.5,
            "list": [
                "normal string",
                1,
                1.5
            ],
            "nested list": [
                1,
                1.5,
                [
                    "normal string",
                    1,
                    1.5
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    "Multiple": [
        {
            "one": [
                1,
                1.5,
                [
                    "normal string",
                    1,
                    1.5
                ]
            ],
            "two": {
                "int": 1,
                "str": "normal string",
                "float": 1.5,
                "list": [
                    "normal string",
                    1,
                    1.5
                ],
                "nested list": [
                    1,
                    1.5,
                    [
                        "normal string",
                        1,
                        1.5
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "one": [
                1,
                1.5,
                [
                    "normal string",
                    1,
                    1.5
                ]
            ],
            "two": {
                "int": 1,
                "str": "normal string",
                "float": 1.5,
                "list": [
                    "normal string",
                    1,
                    1.5
                ],
                "nested list": [
                    1,
                    1.5,
                    [
                        "normal string",
                        1,
                        1.5
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "one": [
                1,
                1.5,
                [
                    "normal string",
                    1,
                    1.5
                ]
            ],
            "two": {
                "int": 1,
                "str": "normal string",
                "float": 1.5,
                "list": [
                    "normal string",
                    1,
                    1.5
                ],
                "nested list": [
                    1,
                    1.5,
                    [
                        "normal string",
                        1,
                        1.5
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

#### `class` instance to JSON

- A simple solution:

```py
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(
            self,
            data_str,
            data_int,
            data_float,
            data_list,
            data_n_list,
            data_dict,
            data_n_dict):
        self.str_data = data_str
        self.int_data = data_int
        self.float_data = data_float
        self.list_data = data_list
        self.nested_list = data_n_list
        self.dictionary = data_dict
        self.nested_dictionary = data_n_dict


foo = Foo(
    str_data,
    int_data,
    float_data,
    list_data,
    nested_list,
    dictionary,
    nested_dictionary)

# Because the JSON object is a Python dictionary. 
result = json.dumps(foo.__dict__, indent=4)
# See table above.

# or with built-in function that accesses .__dict__ for you, called vars()
# result = json.dumps(vars(foo), indent=4)

print(result) # same as before
```

- Even simpler

```py
class Bar:
    def toJSON(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__,
                          sort_keys=False, indent=4)


bar = Bar()
bar.web = "Stackoverflow"
bar.type = "Knowledge"
bar.is_the_best = True
bar.user = Bar()
bar.user.name = "Milovan"
bar.user.age = 34

print(bar.toJSON())
```

chart response

[image]

output:

```sh
{
    "web": "Stackoverflow",
    "type": "Knowledge",
    "is_the_best": true,
    "user": {
        "name": "Milovan",
        "age": 34
    }
}
```

Comment: Think it must be accepted answer !

Answer (score 6):

You can create a nested dictionary in the above example by declaring a new dictionary inside the default dictionary.

```
import json 
dictionary = {
'fruit':{"Grapes": "10","color": "green"},
'vegetable':{"chilli": "4","color": "red"},
}
result = json.dumps(dictionary, indent = 3)
```

print(result)

Here, I have used indent=3

Reference: https://favtutor.com/blogs/dict-to-json-python

Answer (score 3):

No need to convert it in a string by using `json.dumps()`

```
r = {'is_claimed': 'True', 'rating': 3.5}
file.write(r['is_claimed'])
file.write(str(r['rating']))
```

You can get the values directly from the dict object.

Answer (score 1):

Defining r as a dictionary should do the trick:

```
>>> r: dict = {'is_claimed': 'True', 'rating': 3.5}
>>> print(r['rating'])
3.5
>>> type(r)
<class 'dict'>
```