# How to convert to json file formate in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

Here is my output:

```
xyz information
+-----+------+------+
| A   | B    |  C   |
+-----+------+------+
| 23  |  76  | 87   |
| 76  |  36  | 37   |
| 83  |  06  | 27   |
+-----+------+------+
```

I want to convert this output to json format in python
can anybody suggest how to do that.

Comment: Using python2.7 and it's a output of a command written by me.

Comment: You can try converting the output into a dict instead of a table, and then convert the dict into Json.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745519/converting-dictionary-to-json-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
xyz = '''+-----+------+------+
| A   | B    |  C   |
+-----+------+------+
| 23  |  76  | 87   |
| 76  |  36  | 37   |
| 83  |  06  | 27   |
+-----+------+------+'''
```

Do

```
import json
import collections

xyz_rows = [map(str.strip, row.split('|')[1:-1]) for row in xyz.split('\n') if '|' in row]
xyz_cols = collections.OrderedDict() # OrderedDict to preserve column order
for column in zip(*xyz_rows): # rows to columns
    xyz_cols[column[0]] = column[1:]

xyz_json = json.dumps(xyz_cols)
```

`xyz_json` contains

```
'{"A": ["23", "76", "83"], "B": ["76", "36", "06"], "C": ["87", "37", "27"]}'
```