# JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary

In Python 3, to load json previously saved like this:

`json.dumps(dictionary)`

the output is something like

`{"('Hello',)": 6, "('Hi',)": 5}`

when I use

`json.loads({"('Hello',)": 6, "('Hi',)": 5})`

it doesn't work, this happens:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'
```

Comment: `json.loads('''{"('Hello',)": 6, "('Hi',)": 5}''')`. The `s` in `loads` stands for string.

Comment: Looks like you already are dealing with the actual dictionary and not a string. How are you reading in the data you dumped?

Answer (score 206):

`json.loads` take a string as input and returns a dictionary as output.

`json.dumps` take a dictionary as input and returns a string as output.

---

With `json.loads({"('Hello',)": 6, "('Hi',)": 5})`,

You are calling `json.loads` with a dictionary as input.

You can fix it as follows (though I'm not quite sure what's the point of that):

```
d1 = {"('Hello',)": 6, "('Hi',)": 5}
s1 = json.dumps(d1)
d2 = json.loads(s1)
```

Comment: Thanx @barak manos this really helped. I had a return data which was `json.loads(data)` . when I decode that using `json.dumps(loadedData)` get rid of the above error and manage to convert that to a python object by `object_hook` .

Comment: To simplify, you can directly convert: d1 = {"('Hello',)": 6, "('Hi',)": 5}   and them 
d2 = json.loads(json.dumps(d1))

Answer (score 28):

```
import json
data = json.load(open('/Users/laxmanjeergal/Desktop/json.json'))
jtopy=json.dumps(data) #json.dumps take a dictionary as input and returns a string as output.
dict_json=json.loads(jtopy) # json.loads take a string as input and returns a dictionary as output.
print(dict_json["shipments"])
```

Answer (score 22):

You are passing a dictionary to a function that expects a string.

This syntax:

```
{"('Hello',)": 6, "('Hi',)": 5}
```

is both a valid Python dictionary literal and a valid JSON object literal. But `loads` doesn't take a dictionary; it takes a string, which it then interprets as JSON and returns the result *as* a dictionary (or string or array or number, depending on the JSON, but usually a dictionary).

If you pass this string to `loads`:

```
'''{"('Hello',)": 6, "('Hi',)": 5}'''
```

then it will return a dictionary that looks a lot like the one you are trying to pass to it.

You could also exploit the similarity of JSON object literals to Python dictionary literals by doing this:

```
json.loads(str({"('Hello',)": 6, "('Hi',)": 5}))
```

But in either case you would just get back the dictionary that you're passing in, so I'm not sure what it would accomplish. What's your goal?

Answer (score 12):

#### [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) is used to decode JSON data

```py
import json

# initialize different data
str_data = 'normal string'
int_data = 1
float_data = 1.50
list_data = [str_data, int_data, float_data]
nested_list = [int_data, float_data, list_data]
dictionary = {
    'int': int_data,
    'str': str_data,
    'float': float_data,
    'list': list_data,
    'nested list': nested_list
}

# convert them to JSON data and then print it
print('String :', json.dumps(str_data))
print('Integer :', json.dumps(int_data))
print('Float :', json.dumps(float_data))
print('List :', json.dumps(list_data))
print('Nested List :', json.dumps(nested_list, indent=4))
print('Dictionary :', json.dumps(dictionary, indent=4))  # the json data will be indented
```

output:

```sh
String : "normal string"
Integer : 1
Float : 1.5
List : ["normal string", 1, 1.5]
Nested List : [
    1,
    1.5,
    [
        "normal string",
        1,
        1.5
    ]
]
Dictionary : {
    "int": 1,
    "str": "normal string",
    "float": 1.5,
    "list": [
        "normal string",
        1,
        1.5
    ],
    "nested list": [
        1,
        1.5,
        [
            "normal string",
            1,
            1.5
        ]
    ]
}
```

- Python Object to JSON Data Conversion

```sh
|                 Python                 |  JSON  |
|:--------------------------------------:|:------:|
|                  dict                  | object |
|               list, tuple              |  array |
|                   str                  | string |
| int, float, int- & float-derived Enums | number |
|                  True                  |  true  |
|                  False                 |  false |
|                  None                  |  null  |
```

#### [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) is used to convert JSON data into Python data.

```py
import json

# initialize different JSON data
arrayJson = '[1, 1.5, ["normal string", 1, 1.5]]'
objectJson = '{"a":1, "b":1.5 , "c":["normal string", 1, 1.5]}'

# convert them to Python Data
list_data = json.loads(arrayJson)
dictionary = json.loads(objectJson)

print('arrayJson to list_data :\n', list_data)
print('\nAccessing the list data :')
print('list_data[2:] =', list_data[2:])
print('list_data[:1] =', list_data[:1])

print('\nobjectJson to dictionary :\n', dictionary)
print('\nAccessing the dictionary :')
print('dictionary[\'a\'] =', dictionary['a'])
print('dictionary[\'c\'] =', dictionary['c'])
```

output:

```sh
arrayJson to list_data :
 [1, 1.5, ['normal string', 1, 1.5]]

Accessing the list data :
list_data[2:] = [['normal string', 1, 1.5]]
list_data[:1] = [1]

objectJson to dictionary :
 {'a': 1, 'b': 1.5, 'c': ['normal string', 1, 1.5]}

Accessing the dictionary :
dictionary['a'] = 1
dictionary['c'] = ['normal string', 1, 1.5]
```

- JSON Data to Python Object Conversion

```sh
|      JSON     | Python |
|:-------------:|:------:|
|     object    |  dict  |
|     array     |  list  |
|     string    |   str  |
|  number (int) |   int  |
| number (real) |  float |
|      true     |  True  |
|     false     |  False |
```

Answer (score 6):

Hey I recently faced this issue while reading the JSON file directly. Just putting it out here if anyone faces this issue while reading json file and then parsing it:

```
jsonfile = open('path/to/file.json','r')
json_data = json.load(jsonfile)
```

Notice that I used load() instead of loads().

Answer (score 1):

I got this error while working with Django REST framework. I used the PostgreSQL materialized view built using native function `json_build_object`. The error disappeared when I switched to the function `jsonb_build_object`.