# Having trouble with JSON and Python

Tags: python, json

New to both so here goes.

I am accessing an api using requests.get that returns an array with clubs and the number of active clubs.

```
clubs = requests.get ('https://api.sumting.com/so on/and so forth', headers={'Authorization': myToken})

clubdata = clubs.json()
print (clubdata)
```

I get something like this:

```
{
  "clubs": [
    {
      "golf_association_id": 1,
      "club_number": 2,
      "club_name": "Otterkill Golf & Country Club",
      "phone": "8454272020",
      "is_dac": false,
      "technology_provider": "Nope",
      "email": "",
      "authorized": null,
      "is_test": false,
      "status": "Active",
      "club_category": "Private",
      "short_name": "",
      "website": "",
      "usga_version": "",
      "handicap_chairperson": "",
      "date": "2019-08-13T14:06:55.928Z",
      "created_at": "2019-08-13T14:06:55.928Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-08-13T14:06:55.928Z",
      "logo": null,
      "club_type": "",
      "alt_text": null,
      "id": 10001,
      "city": "Campbell Hall",
      "state": "NY"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "active_clubs_count": 548
  }
}
```

I need to loop through the "id"s and call another api. The latest of several things I have tried is this:

```
clubs = requests.get ('https://api.sumting.com/so on/and so forth', headers={'Authorization': myToken})

clubdata = clubs.json()
##print (clubdata)

decoded = json.loads(clubdata)

# Access data
for x in decoded['id']:
    print (x['club_name'])
```

Which results in this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Scripts\test-login.py", line 28, in 
    decoded = json.loads(clubdata)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\json__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

I clearly do not understand what I need to understand but have come this far and I am hoping a gentle nudge in the right direction will help me continue down the road.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you passing the result of `clubs.json()` to `json.loads()` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354001/python-json-object-must-be-str-bytes-or-bytearray-not-dict)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like maybe you aren't grabbing the proper part of the JSON. Before you do the loop, try printing out the `clubs` key (since the response returns a key named `"clubs"`), e.g.

```
print(decoded['clubs']) # <-- does this show you the list?
```

If the above shows an error, then figure out why.  E.g. what does `print(decoded.keys())` return?  If the above shows you the list of clubs, then you can loop over it, e.g.

```
for x in decoded['clubs']:
    print (x['club_name'])
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: print (clubdata["clubs"][1]["id"])           works and has gotten me further along. I have had an "aha" moment. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to help! Remember to upvote comments/answers that you find helpful.