# Importing Data from a JSON to django AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make an E-commerce website from the tutorial series- [Django Ecommerce Website | Add to Cart Functionality | Part 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=woORrr3QNh8&list=PL-51WBLyFTg0omnamUjL1TCVov7yDTRng&index=4) in django freamwork.

My **views.py** is:

```
def updateItem(request):
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']

    print('productId: ', productId)
    print('action: ', action)
    return JsonResponse('Item was added', safe=False)
```

My js file is:

```
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')
console.log('updateBtns length:', updateBtns.length);
for(var i=0; i<updateBtns.length; i++){
  updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    var productId = this.dataset.product
    var action = this.dataset.action
    console.log('product ID: ', productId, "Action: ", action)
    console.log('User: ', user)
    if (user == 'AnonymousUser'){
      console.log('user is not authnticated');
    }
    else{
      updateUserOrder(productId, action);
    }
  })
}
function updateUserOrder(productId, action){
  console.log('user is authenticatred, sending data')
  var url = '/update_item/'
  fetch(url,{
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({'productId': productId, 'action': action})
  })
  .then((response) =>{
    return response.json()
  })
  .then((data) =>{
    console.log('data: ', data)
  })
}
```

Here my problem is after adding those line in **updateItem** function in **views.py** the error is shown in the console-

```
data = json.loads(request.data)
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'
```

How can I solve this problem? Actually I do not know about rest API or json clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do:

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
```

As suggest in the console: `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'` and that's completely true. But, it has attribute called [`body`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body)

Specifically, in your js `fetch` you have sent data to `request.body`:

```
    body: JSON.stringify({'productId': productId, 'action': action}) // Here
```

For more about [django_response_and_request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/)

Comment: I try that request.POST line, Now there came the following error-
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not QueryDict

Comment: you don't have to stringify the post data. I ll update accordingly.

Comment: To understand the  `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not QueryDict`, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354001/python-json-object-must-be-str-bytes-or-bytearray-not-dict)

Comment: thanks Biplove Lamichhane, the error gone, but another problem appered. I need te print the productID inconsole but this line-print('productId: ', productId), I do not know why, but now no message is shown in console

Comment: Do you get any error... or just not showing like `productId: ` ?

Comment: I don't get any error now after add your code, just wanna show the productId in console.... later I will pass that in the database

Comment: You have to confirm if you are giving data correctly from js. By `console.log(productId)`.

Comment: yeah, I already check it...... will I give you my full project folder link? (if you want)

Comment: Okay, I can look at it.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ku8faObPE1ncIMMZ9rhukLNyjWfAUqB-?usp=sharing

Comment: thanks, Biplove Lamichhane, please check this drive link

Comment: @KanchonGharami Sorry, I was thinking like `ajax` request. So, I said those things. As you are using fetch the only error was `request.data` instead of `request.body`. Btw, I checked your project. Next time try sharing your code from **github**.

Comment: thanks a lot, Biplove Lamichhane, Now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

As a modification to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64027868/3744182) by [Biplove Lamichhane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10860596/biplove-lamichhane):

> ```
> data = json.loads(request.body)
> ```

I needed instead to do:

```
data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
```

As I was getting bytes from UI.