# Extracting JSON data by index in Python

Tags: python, json

There are many similar paths in my full JSON data result, but I want to pull out specific instances. I thought the best way to do that would be to simply indicate the index from which I want to pull the data.

Here's a snippet of my JSON:

```
"data":[
      {
         "id":"xxxx",
         "account_type":"None",
         "description":"Lorem Ipsum",
         "score":xx,
         "jumpers":xxxxx,
         "friends":xxx,
         "global":xxxxxxx,
         "hidden":true,
         "location":"xxxx, xx",
         "name":"xxxxx",
```

Here's what I ran:

```
url = 'my_url'
access_token = 'my_token'

result = requests.get(url,headers={'Content-Type':'application/json','Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token)})
json = result.json()
company = json['data'][0,9]
print(company)
```

Where [0] is the first dataset beneath "data", and [9] for the "name" position. Obviously, this isn't the right way to do it, given the output **TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple**

How do I access the first instance of 'name' by index? How does this process work for pulling other information by index?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

In Python, json data usually is handled as a dictionary, so the easiest way to access information is by the dictionary key. Here is an example to access the "name" parameter in your json data

```py
import json

data = """
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "xxxx",
      "account_type": "None",
      "description": "Lorem Ipsum",
      "engagement_score": "xx",
      "jumpers": "xxxxx",
      "friends": "xxx",
      "global": "xxxxxxx",
      "hidden": true,
      "location": "xxxx, xx",
      "name": "your_name"
    }
  ]
}

"""

json_data = json.loads(data)

print(json_data['data'][0]['name'])
```

Your code returned an error because you can't use a Tuple to index a list in Python, to index nested lists, just sequence the index, like this:

```py
data = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]
]

print(data[0][0])
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer @Leonardo, and it certainly does the job. I failed to mention I was looking to do this at scale over hundreds of different JSON results, so bringing in the dataset for each scrape would be unfeasible. I did come up with another way (answer below) using your insight for direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Python as of version 3.6, [insertion order of keys in dictionaries is preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6). So it is also possible to access dictionary values based on insertion order (i.e. integer index). See the example below that shows accessing the value of attribute 'name' using its index of 3 which retrieves the correct value of 'xxxxx'.

Code:

```
import json

data_json='''[{"id":"xxxx","account_type":"None","attrib":true,"name":"xxxxx"}]'''

data_py = json.loads(data_json)
print("data_json",data_json)
print("data_py:",data_py)
print("name:",list(data_py[0].values())[3])
```

Output:

```
data_json [{"id":"xxxx","account_type":"None","attrib":true,"name":"xxxxx"}]
data_py: [{'id': 'xxxx', 'account_type': 'None', 'attrib': True, 'name': 'xxxxx'}]
name: xxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Without bringing in the JSON result for each of the URLs I want to scrape, this is what I ran:

```
url = 'my_url'
access_token = 'my_token'

result = requests.get(url,headers={'Content-Type':'application/json','Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token)})
#Get JSON data   
response = result.json()
#Take the dictionary input and produce string output
json_dump = json.dumps(response)
#Take string input and produce dictionary output
dict_json = json.loads(json_dump)
print(dict_json['data'][0]['name'])
```

---

```
Output: 'Fido'
```

This solution may not be the most elegant one, (I plead ignorance) but it was taken from the guidance of the original answer and this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59980773/16880647