# how to send dict parameters to aws lambda event

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, dictionary, aws-lambda

please help, i am trying to convert a working python code to AWS lambda python function but i am not sure to pass lambda test event in dict format.

i have tried below code .. normal python execution works fine. but when i apply it to lambda python function i am getting fault error at input string i.e., vpn

### Working code

```
    from zeep import Client
    client = Client('http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx?wsdl')
    request_data = {
        'countryCode': 'Scotland',
        'year': 2018}
    print(client.service.GetHolidaysForYear(**request_data))
```

### Not working

```
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        client = Client('http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx?wsdl')
        result = client.service.GetHolidaysForYear(event['vpn'])
        return result
```

lambda test event

```
    {
      "vpn": {
        "countryCode": "Scotland",
        "year": 2018
        }
    }
```

## AWS lambda error

"errorMessage": "For input string: "{'countryCode': 'Scotland', 'year': 2018}"",
"errorType": "Fault",

Comment: I think there is format error in your json. please insert colon : between "year" and 2018

Comment: hi, sorry that was a manual type mistake.. but lambda execution fails with correct JSON,

Comment: I checked on my lambda both event["vpn"] and request_data has type dict. Please try by passing `**event["vpn"]` as you pass on above code.

Comment: with that i am getting this error -----   "errorMessage": "Unable to marshal response: Object of type GetHolidaysForYearOperationResult is not JSON serializable",

Comment: to fix marshal error try `data=json.loads(event["vpn"])` and send **data in parameter

Comment: still no luck.. now i got ----  {
  "errorMessage": "the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict",
  "errorType": "TypeError",

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354001/json-object-must-be-str-bytes-or-bytearray-not-dict) answer. You can try with json.dumps() and then json.loads() Hope this works

Comment: In the working code you are passing `**request_data` which unpacks the `request_data` dict into keyword arguments, but in the failing case you're passing `event['vpn']` as a dict.