# how to get the object with keys/value nested inside tuple from a Json output?

Tags: python, json, tuples

how to get the object with keys/value nested inside tuple from a Json data ? I have been trying to get the below Json output for an api request and loaded the Json output - but i end up with this error

```
the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not tuple
```

i wrote a code like this:

```
output = json.loads(output)
print(output)
```

The output i get

```
('{\n  "architecture" : "x86_64",\n  "billingProducts" : null,\n  "devpayProductCodes" : null,\n  "marketplaceProductCodes" : null,\n  "imageId" : "****",\n  "instanceId" : "***",\n  "instanceType" : "t3.2xlarge",\n  "kernelId" : null,\n  "pendingTime" : "2022-05-19T17:32:35Z",\n  "privateIp" : "***",\n  "ramdiskId" : null,\n  "version" : "2017-09-30"\n}', '  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current\n                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed\n\n  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0\n100    56  100    56    0     0  56000      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 56000\n  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current\n                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed\n\n  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0\n100   479  100   479    0     0   467k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  467k\n')
output = json.loads(output)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not tuple
```

Comment: clearly whatever output is in not JSON. Can you show the code for inital assignment of `output`'s value?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354001/json-object-must-be-str-bytes-or-bytearray-not-dict/59980773#59980773

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According previous answer, it's almost correct. Must be

> output = json.loads(output[0])

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, the variable `output` must be of type `bytes`, `string`, or `bytearray`.

If we take a deeper look, the tuple actually only contains one `string` element. So, I believe we're supposed to get that `string` element!

We can do so using this:

```py
output = json.loads(output)[0] # Tuples are just like arrays
```

So, now the variable `output` is of type `string`!

If this doesn't work, perhaps try renaming the `output` variable as such:

```py
variable = json.loads(output)[0]
```

Sorry if this is incorrect!

Comment: thank you for you reply. It worked with brackets ^ shown in the previous answer @ztilB