# Counter object to JSON string in Python

Tags: python, json

I am new in Python and would appreciate your help.
I got this counter object :

```
Counter({1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10, 4: 10, 5: 10, 6: 10, 7: 10, 8: 10, 9: 10, 10: 
        10})
```

Each key is actually a userId with a count `number_of_posts` as a value.

So what I finally need is to convert this counter object to a JSON like so :

```
{ 
    “user”:
        {
            id: int
            number_of_posts: int
        }
}
```

Please advise..
Thanks
Raffi

Comment: Probably duplicated of [Converting Dictionary to JSON in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745519/converting-dictionary-to-json-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

This might help. I am iterating over your dictionary and creating the required structure.

```
from  collections import Counter
a = Counter({1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10, 4: 10, 5: 10, 6: 10, 7: 10, 8: 10, 9: 10, 10:10})
d = {"user": []}
for k,v in a.items():
    d["user"].append({"id": k, "number_of_posts": v})

print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'user': [{'number_of_posts': 10, 'id': 1}, {'number_of_posts': 10, 'id': 2}, {'number_of_posts': 10, 'id': 3}, {'number_of_posts': 10, 'id': 4}, {'number_of_posts': 10, 'id': 5}, {'number_of_posts': 10, 'id': 6}, {'number_of_posts': 10, 'id': 7}, {'number_of_posts': 10, 'id': 8}, {'number_of_posts': 10, 'id': 9}, {'number_of_posts': 10, 'id': 10}]}
```

Answer (score -1):

Generate the required format, and then convert it to the JSON type

```
import json

ret = {}
li = []
for key, value in dic.items():
    ret['id'] = key
    ret['number'] = value
    li.append(ret)
    ret = {}
ret['user'] = li
return json.dumps(ret)
```