# How to assign a json to another without using loop

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have a json like this:

```
{
"name": "ehsan",
"family": "shirzadi",
"age": 20,
"address": "...",
"tel": "..."
}
```

I have another json like this:

```
{
"name": "ali",
"family": "rezayee",
}
```

Is there away to update my first json's name and family with the second json without using a loop and assigning one by one?

Answer (score 3):

If we assume the first json is `j1` and the second `j2` then the following will update `j1` with values in `j2`:

```
j1.update(j2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [import / export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745519/converting-dictionary-to-json-in-python) `json` files to / from dictionaries. This means you can utilise [`dict.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update):

```
d1 = {
"name": "ehsan",
"family": "shirzadi",
"age": 20,
"address": "...",
}

d2 = {
"name": "ali",
"family": "rezayee",
}

d1.update(d2)

print(d1)

{'name': 'ali', 'family': 'rezayee',
 'age': 20, 'address': '...'}
```