# JSON.parse() returning string from PythonShell string

Tags: javascript, python, json, node.js, javascript-objects

I'm using PythonShell from Node to run a Python script that returns a Python dict like so (in Python):

```
{ "playedStatus": game['playedStatus'].encode('ascii'),
"awayTeamAbb": game['awayTeamAbb'].encode('ascii'),
"homeTeamAbb": game['homeTeamAbb'].encode('ascii'),
"sport": 'NFL'}
```

When the Python dict is passed back to Node it's in string format like so:

```
{'home': 'CHI', 'sport': 'NFL', 'playedStatus': 'UNPLAYED', 'away': 'SEA'}
```

I've tried to run this string through JSON.parse in a couple different ways to use it as a Javascript object. However, I continue to get a string back instead of an object.

```
let parsed_JSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(python_string_object));
console.log(typeof parsed_JSON); //returns 'string'
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I convert this into an object?

Comment: What datatype is `python_string_object`? If it's already a string, just drop the `JSON.stringify` and use `JSON.parse(python_string_object)`

Comment: I believe you have to take the object apart and then put it back together.  JSON parsing is at the heart of platforms that pass data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Dictionary to JSON in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745519/converting-dictionary-to-json-in-python)

Comment: @mindfolded actually no, it's a different question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get your **python** script to return the JSON dump not the dict:

```
import json

my_dict = {'home': 'CHI', 'sport': 'NFL', 'playedStatus': 'UNPLAYED', 'away': 'SEA'}
json_dict = json.dumps(my_dict)
print(json_dict)
```

then in your **node** side get python-shell to parse using **json mode** and you're done:

```
const PythonShell = require('python-shell');

const pyshell = new PythonShell('script.py', { mode: 'json' });
pyshell.on('message', function (response) {
  console.log(response); // response is already an object!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take your dictionary and use python's `json` package to turn it into proper json. First, use `json.loads()` to turn the dictionary to a string and then you can use `json.dumps()` and return the result in your python script to make sure the dictionary is output in json form.

I believe this is a duplicate of this question: [Converting Dictionary to JSON in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745519/converting-dictionary-to-json-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

```js
python_string_object={'home': 'CHI', 'sport': 'NFL', 'playedStatus': 'UNPLAYED', 'away': 'SEA'}

let parsed_JSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(python_string_object));

console.log(typeof parsed_JSON);//object

python_string_object="{'home': 'CHI', 'sport': 'NFL', 'playedStatus': 'UNPLAYED', 'away': 'SEA'}"

let parsed_JSON2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(python_string_object));

console.log(typeof parsed_JSON2);//string
```

If you do a typeOf on your python_string_object right when you get it, it will be of type string. there is no need to JSON.stringify()2 it