# Python extract values from JSON variable - TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json

I got dictionary from code below following [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745519/converting-dictionary-to-json-in-python)

and need to get Application name,source and message for every key in dictionary so i tried to transfer it in JSON file

```
 if mail["Subject"].find("example error alert") > 0 :
          body = get_email_body(mail)
          info = {}
          segments = body.split(' ')
          for line in body.splitlines():
            if 'Application name' and 'null' in line:
                 info['test'] = segments[0] + ' ' + segments[1] + ' ' + segments[2]  + ' ' + segments[3] + ' ' + segments[4]
            elif 'Application name' in line:
                 info['test'] = segments[0] + ' ' + segments[1] + ' ' + segments[2]  + ' ' + segments[3] + ' ' + segments[4] + ' ' + segments[5] + segments[6] + ' ' + segments[7] +  ' ' + segments[8] + ' ' + segments[9]
            r = json.dumps(info['test'])
            loaded_r = json.loads(r)
            print(str(r['Source']))
```

i have this dictionary

print(info['test'])

```
Application name: example.service
Source: example_host_1|exampleHost1
Timestamp: 2019-01-22T00:00:43.901Z
Message:

Application name: example.api
Source: example_host_2|exampleHost2
Timestamp: 2019-01-23T07:42:12.649Z
Message: HTTP"GET" "/api/endpoint/groups" responded 500
```

i converted it to JSON without error

```
r = json.dumps(info['test'])
          loaded_r = json.loads(r)
```

and when try extract Application_name from it:

```
loaded_r['Application name']
```

or Source

```
loaded_r['Source']
```

i'm getting `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

as suggested by duplicate link tried also  `print (loaded_r['Source'][0])` and  `print(str(r['Source']))` but the same

Message body example (used segments to leave only first some lines to remove duplicates):

```
Source: example_host_1
Timestamp: 2019-01-22T00:00:43.901Z

Message: null



For instructions please see: wiki_link


Application name: example.api
Source: example_host_2
Timestamp: 2019-01-23T07:42:12.649Z
Message: HTTP "GET" "/api/endpoint/groups" responded 500 in 7795.6441 ms


Application name: service.API
Source: example_host_2
Timestamp: 2019-01-23T07:42:12.646Z
Message: Unhandled exception



For instructions please see: example_wiki_link
```

Dictionary stored in `info` variable

```
{'test': '\r\nApplication name: app.service\r\nSource: example_host_1\r\nTimestamp: 2019-01-22T00:00:43.901Z\r\nMessage:'}
{'test': '\r\nApplication name: app.API\r\nSource: adc266f53205\r\nTimestamp: 2019-01-23T07:42:12.649Z\r\nMessage: HTTP"GET" "/api/endpoint/groups" responded 500'}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I seeing "TypeError: string indices must be integers"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077675/why-am-i-seeing-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers)

Answer (score 0):

I think `loaded_r` is a string and not a dictionary.

Comment: yes, i just followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745519/converting-dictionary-to-json-in-python, how can i extract Application name, Source and Message from it ?

Comment: Please post an example of `body`.

Comment: just posted Mike, thanks, in order to avoid duplicates i used segments block to cut it off

Answer (score 0):

I think i'm good now, made some "mumbo-jumbo" but it works, converted dictionary to string and then used regex.Thanks everyone

```
res = ','.join([','.join(i) for i in info.items()])
          x = res.replace('test,','')

          regex1=r'Application name:\s*(.+?)\s+Source'
          regex2=r'Source:\s*(.+?)\s+Timestamp:'
          regex3 = r'(?<!^)Message:\s*.*'
          a = re.findall(regex1 ,x)
          b = re.findall(regex2 ,x)
          c = re.findall(regex3, x)
          print (a, b, c)
```