# how to assign double quotes to json data - Python

Tags: python, json

I have a json which looks like the below. When i validate json, i get an error "Invalid Json" since i have just a single quote and also, there is `u` which i can't tell why it is there.

```
{u'domain': u'127.0.0.1', u'user_id': u'example.com', u'sender': u'shop_1'}
```

The Json above is invalid. How can i make the json appear with double quotes and also remove the `u` from the response to get a valid json.

PS: Beginner with Python

Comment: how do you create that json?

Comment: If what you've showed, is your json file, just replace `u'` and `'` with `"`s. You can do that in your text editor of choice, or even in python, before loading, run `text.replace("u'", '"').replace("'", '"')`

Comment: This is a Python object (saved as string ?!), which is not valid JSON.

Comment: json.dumps() returns the JSON string representation of the python dict. https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745519/converting-dictionary-to-json

Comment: Btw, You are still using Python2; you should switch to Python3 which is around for a decade or more now.  The `u` in front of the string literal marks it as a unicode string (in Python3 that is the normal string, but in Python2 is wasn't).

Comment: that is not a json. that looks like a python dictionary literal. are you simply dumping the string representation of a dictionary and imagining it will be JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `json.dumps()` for that:

```
>>> import json
>>> my_json = {u'domain': u'127.0.0.1', u'user_id': u'example.com', u'sender': u'shop_1'}
>>> print(json.dumps(my_json))
{"domain": "127.0.0.1", "user_id": "example.com", "sender": "shop_1"}
```

The `'u` that you see at the start of each string is an indication that this is a unicode string:

- [What's the u prefix in a Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string)
- https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings