# How to store a dictionary with SQLAlchemy and SQLite3

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to store a column with a dictionary data type. I've CTRL + F in the docs but the only mention of 'dictionary' doesn't help.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html

Here is an example I have of an integer data type if you need a reference:

```py
friend_code = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
```

Comment: dictionary isn't a SQL data type. Is this just for storage? Store it as a binary blob with an appropriate index.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26745519/2144390) might help.