# how to prase a dictionarty object in python?

Tags: python, reactjs

I am reciving this dictionary object from a react native client. i am using django rest framework as back end. i was to parse the values of pushToken and user object in my django backend.

Here is the object,

```json
{
  'pushToken': { 'type': 'expo', 'data': 'ExponentPushToken[OQ927mOVsi3_j2e]' },
  'user': '{"token":"78d7fa3e903b61ac14c0119c9676b24512","user_id":3,"username":"vitor","email":"vitor@reactnative.com"}',
}
```

So far i have tried to covert in into json object using json.dump()... But it did not works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting dictionary to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745519/converting-dictionary-to-json)

Answer (score 1):

**json.dumps()** will convert the dict object to string in order to send via an API,
alternatively **json.loads()** is used to load a JSON string into a dictionary.

**json.dump()** is a **different command** where it will ask for a filename where you want to store this JSON.

If it is already a **dictionary**, try accessing the **key-value pairs.**

for example say **d =** {'pushToken': {'type': 'expo', 'data': 'ExponentPushToken[OQ927mOVsi3_j2e]'}, 'user': '{"token":"78d7fa3e903b61ac14c0119c9676b24512","user_id":3,"username":"vitor","email":"vitor@reactnative.com"}'}

**d['pushToken']['type'] will give 'expo'**

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to copy it? Here is what I got from JSON formatter,

```
{
   "pushToken":{
      "type":"expo",
      "data":"ExponentPushToken[OQ927mOVsi3_j2e]"
   },
   "user":"{\"token\":\"78d7fa3e903b61ac14c0119c9676b24512\",\"user_id\":3,\"username\":\"vitor\",\"email\":\"vitor@reactnative.com\"}"
}
```

Try to [validate your JSON](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) first then you can dump it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).