# Remove aprostrophe from dataset - Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, formatting

I need to format this dict into json format: replacing the general aprostrophe is no problem. I have trouble with replacing the aprostrophe in the value of "cityTo"

```
data = {
'id': 'xxx',
'flyFrom': 'HAM',
'flyTo': 'GND', 
'cityFrom': 'Hamburg',
'cityCodeFrom': 'HAM',
'cityTo': "St George's",
'cityCodeTo': 'GND',
'countryFrom': {'code': 'DE',
                'name': 'Germany'}
}
```

Until I noticed this aprostrophe I formatted like this:

```
str(data).replace("'", '"').replace("None", '"None"').replace("False", '"False"').replace("True", '"True"')
```

but this incudes the mentioned aprostrophe .

Comment: It seems like you're asking about the "apostrophe" `'` not the "semicolon" `;`.

Comment: you don't need to use `str` function, you can use `json` package like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745519/converting-dictionary-to-json