# python beautifulsoup how to get data as json format?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, beautifulsoup

I want to get data as json format. Right now I am getting data as dictionary which little bit messy for me. Here is my code:

```
my_dict = {"job_title":[],"time_posted":[],"number_of_proposal":[],"page_link":[]};
for page_num in range(1, 12):
    time.sleep(3)
    url = (
        f'my_url').format(page_num)
    print(url)
    headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
    print(headers)
    headers.update(
        {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0', })
    print(headers)
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')

    box = soup.select('.item__top_container⤍ListItem⤚3pRrO')
    for i in box:
        job_title = i.select('.item__title⤍ListItem⤚2FRMT')[0].text.lower()
        job_title = job_title.replace('opportunity', ' opportunity').replace(
            'urgent', ' urgent').strip()
        print(job_title)
        time_posted = i.select('time')[0].text.lower()
        remove_month_year = ["month", "year"]
        print(time_posted)
        proposal = i.select(
            '.item__info⤍ListItem⤚1ci50 li:nth-child(3)')[0].text.replace('Proposals', '').strip()
        keywords = ['scrap', 'data mining']
        if(any(key_words in job_title for key_words in keywords)):
            if(not any(remove_m_y in time_posted for remove_m_y in remove_month_year)):
                   my_dict["job_title"].append(job_title)
                   my_dict["time_posted"].append(time_posted)
                   my_dict["number_of_proposal"].append(proposal)
                   my_dict["page_link"].append(url)
```

my dictionary data look like this:

```
{'job_title': ['web scraping of product reviews', 'yell web scraping in python', 'google business scraping',],'time_posted': ['6 days ago', '9 days ago', '3 days ago'], 'page_link': ['url1','url2','url3']}
```

My expected result will be look like this:

```
{"job_title":"web scraping of product reviews","time_posted":"6 days ago","page_link":"url1"},{"job_title":"yell web scraping in python","time_posted":"9 days ago","page_link":"url2"}
```

Comment: Your expected result is invalid JSON. Do you mean a `dict`?

Comment: Freddy Mcloughlan I don't know why it's invalid JSON. I just need the data as my expected result so it could be json or whatever

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32824345/14141223 Use `json.dumps(dictionary)`

Comment: Freddy Mcloughlan no

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to print your dictionary as a JSON string? or the invalid (for JSON at least) formatted string in your example?

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. You just want a different structure.

Comment: I want to see data as my expected result

Comment: Then instead of putting values into 4 different list, put them in a single dict and add that dict into a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the structure with the following code:

```
my_list = []

for i in range(len(my_dict["job_title"])):
    my_list.append({
        "job_title": my_dict["job_title"][i],
        "time_posted": my_dict["time_posted"][i],
        "number_of_proposal": my_dict["number_of_proposal"][i],
        "page_link": my_dict["page_link"][i]
    })
```

Even better would be to directly create the list in the first loop like you need it in the end.

```
my_list = []
for i in box:
    job_title = i.select('.item__title⤍ListItem⤚2FRMT')[0].text.lower()
    job_title = job_title.replace('opportunity', ' opportunity').replace(
        'urgent', ' urgent').strip()
    print(job_title)
    time_posted = i.select('time')[0].text.lower()
    remove_month_year = ["month", "year"]
    print(time_posted)
    proposal = i.select(
        '.item__info⤍ListItem⤚1ci50 li:nth-child(3)')[0].text.replace('Proposals', '').strip()
    keywords = ['scrap', 'data mining']
    if(any(key_words in job_title for key_words in keywords)):
        if(not any(remove_m_y in time_posted for remove_m_y in remove_month_year)):
            my_list.append({
                "job_title": job_title,
                "time_posted": time_posted,
                "number_of_proposal": number_of_proposal,
                "page_link": page_link
            })
```

Comment: jugi Thanks. upvote my question please

Comment: @Farhan, you can't just ask for upvotes. You receive upvotes when your question is clear, well researched and useful. Please edit your question to be more so, if you would like upvotes

Answer (score 0):

I think you are defining your data structure wrong. From your expected result I understand that you want:
*{"job_title": "title 1", "time_posted":"6 days ago" ... }, {"job_title": "title2"...}*

So, a list of dictionaries. Now you have a dictionary with list type values.

You have two options:

1.- Process your dictionary to adquire your desired structure

```
final_list = []

for _ in range(len(my_dict["job_title"])):
    item_dict = {}
    for key in my_dict:
        item_dict[key] = my_dict[key].pop(0)
    final_list.append(item_dict)

print(final_list) 
# [{'job_title': 'web scraping of product reviews', 'time_posted': '6 days ago', 'page_link': 'url1'}, {'job_title': 'yell web scraping in python', 'time_posted': '9 days ago', 'page_link': 'url2'}, {'job_title': 'google business scraping', 'time_posted': '3 days ago', 'page_link': 'url3'}]
```

2.- Same as user jugi mentioned, It's the best option. He has answered while I was writing this, so I'll post this anyways because my option 1 is slightly different.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a dictionary for each entry with a comprehension:

```
# Just using x because it's shorter. This does not create a copy
x = my_dict
x = [{'job_title': x['job_title'][i], 'time_posted': x['time_posted'][i],
      'page_link': x['page_link'][i]} for i in range(len(x['page_link']))]
```

```
>>> x
[{'job_title': 'web scraping of product reviews',
  'page_link': 'url1',
  'time_posted': '6 days ago'},
 {'job_title': 'yell web scraping in python',
  'page_link': 'url2',
  'time_posted': '9 days ago'},
 {'job_title': 'google business scraping',
  'page_link': 'url3',
  'time_posted': '3 days ago'}]
```

Comment: did you read my question?  if not then see what will be my expected result. It's not just converting dic to json.