# How to convert a python dict to json in order to submit to kinesis

Tags: python, json

So I am trying to push some data into kinesis stream using Python and the record needs to be in JSON format but for the life of me I cant seem to get it correct.

I have a python dict object:

```
o = {'Name':'John Doe'}
```

I want to submit this to kinesis, so I did the following:

```
//omitting kinesis initialisation and all..
response = kinesis_client.put_records(
   StreamName='kinesis_test_stream',
   Records=json.dumps(o)
)
```

It gives me following error:

> type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'list'>, <class 'tuple'>

So instead of `json.dumps(o)` I tried `Records=json.loads(json.dumps(o))`

Then it gives me this error:

> type: <class 'dict'>, valid types: <class 'list'>, <class 'tuple'>

I have been banging my head around this for an hour now, I think it should be something very small and silly that I am missing.

I tried [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745519/converting-dictionary-to-json) but nothing helped.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I think the error comes from kinesis not json.dumps. can you try jsut under your declaration to do print(json.dumps(o))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, the `Records` parameter expects a list. Try

```
response = kinesis_client.put_records(
   StreamName='kinesis_test_stream',
   Records=[o]
)
```

And check [the docs for `put_records`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/kinesis.html#Kinesis.Client.put_records).