# Python Dictionary as Valid jSon?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

in python I have:

```
dict = {}
dict['test'] = 'test'
```

when I print I get:

```
{'test':'test'}
```

How can I make it like this:

```
{"test":"test"}
```

Please Note, replace won't work as test may be test't...

I tried:

```
dict = {}
dict["test"] = "test"
```

Comment: Python's standard library has a module specifically for working with JSON, please do basic research before asking on SO.

Comment: You can use the `json` module as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32824345/11078962).

Comment: Googling "python json" would have given you the answer after a few seconds. Posting this question was more effort than doing the research.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - dump dict as a json string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668511/python-dump-dict-as-a-json-string)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json.dumps()`
For example, if you use `print json.dumps(dict)` you should get the desired output.

Additionally, as suggested in a different related question, you may construct your own version of a dict with special printing:

[How to create a Python dictionary with double quotes as default quote format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283725/how-to-create-a-python-dictionary-with-double-quotes-as-default-quote-format)